# use Cube Functions to get filtered dimensions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, cube, powerpivot

How do you get a list of filtered dimentions from a cube function

say I had a dimention table of addresses:

```
1234  Any Street  Detroit  MI 48229
55588 187th St E  Seattle  WA 98888
4     Blossum Ave Wescotte AL 66554
```

How could I get a CUBERANKEDMEMBER list of street addresses with a certain zip?

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
=cubeset("powerpivot", "nonempty([City].[Zip].children, [Measure].[Count of City])", "set")
```

and then use

```
=Cuberankmember("powerpivot", set, 1)
=Cuberankmember("powerpivot", set, 2)
....
```

where `set` is the name of cell where first formula is.